# "Internet not working" message, when I try to update Ubuntu, when internet is working fine

Tags: upgrade, updates, internet-connection

I am getting the message Internet Not working when I try to 
update Ubuntu.

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.0.0-19-generic_3.0.0-19.32_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.193 80]

Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.0.0-19_3.0.0-19.32_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.193 80]
```

But my internet is working fine, since i am able to download all files via internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Manager Error: Failed to fetch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36125/update-manager-error-failed-to-fetch)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a error with your computer. Because there is no such a file(linux-headers-3.0.0-19_3.0.0-19.32_all.deb) in the "in.archive.ubuntu.com" server.

Try to run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

If this not works change the repository mirror. [/etc/apt/sources.list]